# In Vulgate in Apocalypsis 20:4, why does it say "et regnaverunt cum Christo mille *annis*" (ablative?), rather than "...annos" (accusative)?

Tags: vulgata, ablative, accusative

In Vulgate in Apocalypsis 20:4, why does it say "*et regnaverunt cum Christo mille **annis***" (ablative? Or is it dative?), rather than "*et regnaverunt cum Christo mille **annos***" (accusative)? They reigned with Christ for a thousand years. As far as I know, "*for (some period of time)*" is usually expressed with an accusative, rather than with an ablative.

Comment: Even among the classical writers (though perhaps mainly later ones), the ablative is sometimes found instead of an accusative to express duration/extent of time. I've definitely seen examples in the letters of Pliny the Younger and possibly Seneca the Younger.

Comment: Pliny 4.13: *ipse **pauculis** adhuc **diebus** in Tusculano commorabor, ut opusculum quod est in manibus absolvam.*

Comment: It's interesting that the [Greek](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/revelation/20-4.htm) does have an accusative there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the grammars, the accusative answers the question “how long”, and the ablative tells us “when” or “within which time”. But I suspect that by the time of Jerome this distinction was no longer operative.

Comment: I thought that, in the spoken language at the time of Jerome, it is the ablative that was going lost, not the accusative.

Comment: @FlatAssembler That's a little later.

Comment: @cmw What do you mean?